# Rails 4 has many through and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, single-table-inheritance

I would like to assign teacher skills in this case to a maths teacher but I'm not sure if I have the correct set up. When I try to assign TeacherSkills to a Teacher in the console I encounter the errors show below.

I have used [RailsCasts episode#17](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised)  but can not clear these errors. Can anyone offer some advice on the correct set up to achieve the has many through associations with STI.

```
m = MathTeacher.first
m.math_teacher_skill_ids
SELECT `math_teacher_skils`.id FROM `math_teacher_skills`  WHERE`math_teacher_skills`.`math_teacher_id` = 1 => [] 
m.math_teacher_skill_ids = [1,2]

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all MathTeacherSkills with 'id': (1, 2) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)


class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class MathTeacher < Teacher
has_many :math_teacher_skills
has_many :skills, :through => :math_teacher_skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :math_teacher_skills
has_many :teachers, through: :math_teacher_skills
end

class MathTeacherSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :skill
belongs_to :math_teacher
end


#Relevant schema
create_table "math_teacher_skills", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "math_teacher_id"
t.integer  "skill_id"
end

create_table "skills", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "name"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides a simpler way to establish a many-to-many relationship, with has_and_belong_to_many. See more information here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

If you implement this, it might look like this:

```
class MathTeacher < Teacher
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :math_teachers
end
```

Which you could call like this (assuming you have created the appropriate records in the db):

```
m = MathTeacher.first
m.skills
m.skills.pluck(:id) # if you want just the ids
```

Comment: I realized an error in the question itself. In my situation skill is relevant only to the MathTeacher and any other type of teacher would have their own skills. The corrected code sample now reflects the actual problem.

Comment: I see. I think you're still making it more complicated than it needs to be. A math teacher still has many skills, regardless of what you call the intermediate table.

Comment: On reviewing your error, I also noticed that you may not actually have the data in your database that you think you do. Are you sure those records exist?

Comment: Your comments were helpful. I moved to a has_and_belongs_to_many solution. I needed to add a little more so I will answer my own question below in case anyone else needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to only display skills relevant to MathTeacher e.g Algebra as opposed to Generic teacher skills such as class room management. Which required the math_teacher_skills table.

I believe the join table is required when using Single Table Inheritance, but I am open to correction.

## Models

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base   
end

class MathTeacher < Teacher
has_and_belongs_to_many :skills, :join_table => 'math_teacher_skills'
end

class Skills
has_and_belongs_to_many :math_teachers, :join_table => 'math_teacher_skills'
end
```

## Schema

```
create_table "math_teacher_skills", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "math_teacher_id"
t.integer  "skill_id"
end

create_table "skills", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "name"
end
```

If you have want to create or edit a MathTeacher you could assign these MathTeacher skills in a view like this.

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:math_teacher, :skills_ids, Skill.all,:id, :name) %>
```